# Can you create group within a group in Active Directory?

Tags: .net, active-directory, active-directory-group

We want to manage all our .net web applications thru active directory. But, we need to write up the configuration in order for service desk to create the infrastructure for it.

In our write up, we are requesting an organization unit (OU) for our department to manage and create AD groups. We want to create 3 groups: DEV, STAGING and PROD to represent our environments. Is it possible to create subgroups within the 3 groups? For example, the AD group DEV would contain 8 groups to represent 8 applications. Also can you add users to these subgroups?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a group *within* a group - groups are leaf-levels objects that exist in the context of an OU (or another container) and don't "contain" other objects.

What you *can* do is create a group `G2` that becomes **member** of another group, e.g. `G1` - but that's a membership relation - **not** a "group within a group" (like one container inside another container) relation.